# Android Java FirebaseFirestore Write Error

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to add my auth users in my Cloud Firestore.  Here is my code below,

```
FirebaseFirestore db;
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

User newUser = new User(nameRegister, surnameRegister, usernameRegister, emailRegister);

db.collection("users")
.add(newUser)
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
            Log.d("TAG", "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
       }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.w("TAG", "Error adding document", e);
       }
});
```

I read official Firebase document and did how they suggest.
I can not write my data to db.

Where am I doing wrong? I am waiting for your help and thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please share the exact error that you get

Comment: Hi @Sergei actually there is no error. I do what anyone do. It doesn't get into the code and the listener doesn't work i think

Comment: Is your `onSuccess` or `onFailure` actually triggered?

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo how can i recognize to is my listener triggered?

Comment: By checking if one or the other is printing something out in the logcat.

Comment: Thank you both. I need to call these another struct in my code. I was trying to do this another onComplete method. That is why my listeners actually not triggered.

Comment: Do you mean the issue has been resolved? If not, please elaborate and provide more context such as the struct. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for interest Yanan. Yes the issue is solved.